# Creating own style - "powerdot error: unknown style"

Tags: powerdot

I am trying to create my own powerdot style by adapting one of the standards, as suggested in section 9 of the [manual](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/rhigginbottom/latex/resources/powerdot-manual.pdf).

I duplicated the file powerdot-paintings.sty and saved as powerdot-mine.sty, and changed the line

```
\ProvidesPackage{powerdot-paintings}[2005/12/10 v1.1 paintings (TDK,HA)]
```

to

```
\ProvidesPackage{powerdot-mine}[first test]
```

I searched through the file and there were no other lines where 'paintings' appeared (except comments).

I saved this file in the same directory as the original powerdot-paintings.sty file, and separately tried in the same directory as the tex file.

If the command is style=paintings then it runs fine (see example below), swapping to style=mine and the error "1613: Class
powerdot Error: unknown style `mine'." is returned.

I am using Texshop on OS X Yosemite.  I did note that if I search for the powerdot style file using the command kpsewhich powerdot-paintings.sty it can find the file, but using the same command for powerdot-mine.sty returns no files.  I don't understand what that command does, found it on another site when trying to find the location of my powerdot style files - but I suspect that the system can't see my file.

```
\documentclass[style=mine]{powerdot}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Powerdot Presentation}
\author{Sharelatex}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{slide}{Slide Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item This is an item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
  \end{itemize}
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a valid package you have to set the date in the form `YYYY/MM/DD`. So

```
\ProvidesPackage{powerdot-mine}[2015/11/02 v0.1 first test]
```

should do the trick.